# PHPExcel, chunkReadFilter, calculate cell

Tags: filter, phpexcel

To read xlsx large files I use parts of reading (chunkReadFilter), but if the file is in the cells of the formula referring to a cell in the beginning of the file, it returns an error #N/A. I think because read another block of data from a file and access to the cells of the formula no longer exists. How to solve it. An example of my code:

```
    $oExcel = new Excel();
    $objReader = $oExcel->CreateObjectExcel2007();
    for ($iList=0;$iList<$list_count;$iList++){
        $iAllStringsTotal += ($row_start - 1);
        $iAllStringsCurrentList = ($row_start - 1);
        for($iStartRow = $row_start; $iStartRow <= $ExelInfo[$iList]['totalRows']; $iStartRow += $iChunkSize) {
            $objReader = $oExcel->SetCreateReader();
            $oChunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();
            $objReader->setReadFilter($oChunkFilter);

            $oChunkFilter->setRows($iStartRow,$iChunkSize);
            $objReader->setReadFilter($oChunkFilter);
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($files['path']);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($iList);
            $sFromCell = 'A'.$iStartRow;
            $aData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,false,$sFromCell);

            // free memory
            unset($objPHPExcel);
            unset($objReader);
            unset($oChunkFilter);

            // parse data
            foreach ($aData as $sKey => $aValue) {
                $iAllStringsCurrentList += 1;
                $iAllStringsTotal += 1;
                // this code parsing data
            }
            // real data rows
            if (count($aData) < $iChunkSize) {
                unset($aData);
                break;
            }
            unset($aData);
            }
    }
```

Comment: One solution is not to chunk read.... if you have a cell that needs calculation and that refers to other cells, then it needs access to those other cells to read/calculate their value. Otherwise, you can try using an explicit call to `getOldCalculatedValue()`, but that isn't ever guaranteed.

Comment: This function helped. Thx